# Share & Sync a list between two different SharePoint farms

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, farm

We have our own SharePoint enterprise server 2013, and our customer has his own SharePoint enterprise server 2013.

Now I am trying to find an approach which allow us to share & sync SharePoint items between the two the independentSharePoint servers (independent farms). As follow:-

1. To create list (Discussion list) inside our SharePoint server
2. Create another list (Discussion list) inside our customer SharePoint server.
3. Users from the two servers can view the discussions and reply to it.
4. Where the replies should be visible to both servers’ users.

So can anyone advice if there is a way to share/sync items between 2 independent servers?
Thanks

Comment: I would use create a hybrid solution with your SharePoint 2013 OnPrem and SharePoint Online and create an external sharing place for your customers in the same place. That's the fastest way unless you want to use LinkedIn groups :)

Comment: @BennySkogberg not sure what you mean by LinkedIn groups  ??also both of us are using on-premise deployment ,, so we do not use SP online..thanks

Comment: It's a very difficult to get things working as you suggest. It's not an easy task making two farms in different domains interchange information for a discussion group. It's much easier to create a LinkedIn group or implementing a hybrid solution. I wouldn't try to create these synced lists in different domains...

Comment: @BennySkogberg so you are saying that sharing and syncing list items in general between 2 different sharepoint farms (2 different sharepoint domain in our case) is not something i can achieve ? i was thing of a pure-development appraoch such as writing a web service on the 2 servers, which reads the items from the one server and add the related items and their modification inside the second server.. not sure if this is a valid appraoch ?

Comment: The problem is to get things synced correctly. What happens when two users in the different environments comment the same threat at the same time? You need to handle this. I'm not saying it can't be done, just that it's complicated...

Comment: @BennySkogberg for sure those tasks is a bit complicated i am not arguing about this, but my question was about the general approach to follow to achieve this ? second point i was also asking if there are some tools which can help in achieving this , rather than building it from scratch ?